# Consuming a web-service that requires SSL certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, ssl

I'm trying to connect to a web-service that requires having the relevant certificate installed on the machine calling the service. I have installed the certificate, but when I try to add this web-service to my Asp.Net MVC project I get the following error:

> There was an error downloading 'https://MyServiceAddress/$metadata'.
>   The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://MyServiceAddress...'.
>   Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'MyServiceDomain'.
>   The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

I can get the WSDL file with my browser and use it to create the client classes, but I cannot add the reference to this web-service using Visual Studio and get the above error message.

Comment: Save the `WSDL` file as `xml` from browser  `save as` by right click . Then keep the file in desktop and add physical path as `url` for `service reference`. Example `C:\\file.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Get wsdl and all xsd it reffers in `xs:import` section. Put it all in one folder and add VS Reference as usual from local wsdl.